# Is there a Django App/Plugin that will do notifications for me?

Tags: javascript, python, django, plugins

Such as Twitter's drop down notifications whenever something happens.

Whenever a user finishes registration, the notification will drop down and say, "Thank you"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use django.contrib.messages if you're using Django >= 1.2?

Read this [Django Advent article on django.contrib.messages](http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/messages-rest-us/). It seems like it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Would [django](https://github.com/leah/django-flash-status) [flash](https://github.com/danielfm/django-flash) message be sufficient for you?